# Strapi: preventing the creation of an entry with the beforeCreate lifecycle hook

Tags: strapi, lifecycle

Is there a way to prevent strapi from creating an entry with the use of the lifecycle hook beforeCreate, because if a just throw an error, the error is thrown but the entry is still created

Throwing the error doesn't prevent strapi from creating the new entry

What could I do?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Strapi lifecycles are ok

When you throw an error from, say, beforeCreate, it will prevent strapi from creating the entry

In my case it was not working, because I have the throw Error inside a try-catch block, then the throw error interrupts the try block but not the beforeCreate

I'm using "throw new ForbiddenError(..." because I read it in a forum

I have a try block because I'm reading a table

I had to use a local variable

You know how...